# Extracting structured binary data (from Kafka) and casting to Integer

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to ingest data into Spark using Python from Kafka. The data from Kafka is in JSON format like this:

```
{"order_id": 56, "customer_id": 772, "taxful_total_price": 154
```

This JSON data is continuously streaming from Kafka. What I want is to read this data in Pyspark python code and write it (unchanged) to the console. (No aggregations yet).

Here is the code:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0- 
10_2.11:2.4.0 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Total-spending-for-top-users")\
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "orders")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()

jsonschema = StructType([StructField("order_id", IntegerType()), 
                    StructField("customer_id", IntegerType()), 
                    StructField("taxful_total_price", IntegerType())])

mta_stream = df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), jsonschema) \
                            .alias("parsed_mta_values"))

mta_data = mta_stream.select("parsed_mta_values.*")

qry = mta_data.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
qry.awaitTermination()
```

And here is the output in the console:

```
| order_id | customer_id | taxful_total_price |
| -------- | ----------- | ------------------ |
|null      |   null      |        null        |
|null      |   null      |        null        |
|null      |   null      |        null        |
|null      |   null      |        null        |
|null      |   null      |        null        |
```

I changed the following lines of the code as follows:

```
mta_stream = df.select(col("value").alias("parsed_mta_values"))
mt = mta_stream.select("parsed_mta_values")

query = mt.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

And I got the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 0
-----------------------------------------

|   parsed_mta_values|
|--------------------|
|[22 7B 5C 22 6F 7...|
|[22 7B 5C 22 6F 7...|
|[22 7B 5C 22 6F 7...|
|[22 7B 5C 22 6F 7...|
|[22 7B 5C 22 6F 7...|
|[22 7B 5C 22 6F 7...|
```

As we can see this is binary data.

How do I convert from binary to string ? The following in the first code I mentioned does not work:

```
mta_stream = df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), jsonschema) \
                            .alias("parsed_mta_values"))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```py
mta_stream = df.select(col("value").cast("string")).alias("parsed_mta_values")) \
               .select(from_json(col("parsed_mta_values"), jsonschema))
```